# MySql Query - Different Results on Different Server Versions

Tags: mysql

I have a query that is returning two different results from two MySql servers i'm running.

This is the query (generated by Entity Framework, I run it directly in MySql to ensure the results are coming back from each server differently):

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN Project1.C1 IS NULL THEN '5' ELSE Project1.data_entered END AS C1
FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X) AS SingleRowTable1
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
    Extent1.data_entered,
    1 AS C1
    FROM  rta_option_data AS Extent1
    INNER JOIN rta_option_field AS Extent2 ON Extent1.rta_option_field_id = Extent2.rta_option_field_id
    WHERE (Extent1.customer_id = 1546) AND (Extent2.Name = 'txtAdverseDelay') ) AS Project1 ON 1 = 1
```

**Server A is running MySql 5.5.28 and returns 5** which is the correct and expected value.

**Server B is running MySql 5.7.12-log and returns null** which is the incorrect and unexpected value.

I'm at a complete loss of how to resolve this, I was planning a server upgrade this weekend but i'm super worried about other similar queries that could be impacted by this.

Additional notes:

1. They are both using the exact same data.
2. When I run the inner query on both servers they return the same results data_entered = null and C1 = null. This is the inner query i'm talking about:

   SELECT 
   Extent1.data_entered,
   1 AS C1
   FROM  rta_option_data AS Extent1
   INNER JOIN rta_option_field AS Extent2 ON Extent1.rta_option_field_id = Extent2.rta_option_field_id
   WHERE (Extent1.customer_id = 1546) AND (Extent2.Name = 'txtAdverseDelay')

Would appreciate any guidance/advice on how to possibly fix this - not sure if there is a setting in MySql or what.

Comment: Can you post sample schema/data so this is reproducible?